# I want to perform multiple user login action using selenium in set up method I am not using testng.xml I am using maven pom.xml only

Tags: java, selenium, pom.xml

Here is my code which I have tried only for one type of user login

```
@BeforeMethod
    public void setUp(){

        log.info("Setting up test");
        prop = new Properties();
        prop.load(new FileInputStream(new File(loginFile)));

        verificationErrors = new StringBuffer();
log.info("Running Firefox Driver");

        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", GECKO_DRIVER_PATH);
 driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
        baseUrl = getSeleniumTarget();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(45, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(80, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.manage().window().setPosition(new Point(0, 0));
        driver.manage().window().maximize();

        WebDriverThreadLocal.setWebDriver(driver);

        login("manageuser");
}

protected void login(String username) {
        LoginPage page = PageFactory.initElements(driver, LoginPage.class);

        log.info("Loging in");
        driver.get(baseUrl + prop.getProperty("login.customerportal"));
        page.setUsername(prop.getProperty(username + ".username"));
        page.setPassword(prop.getProperty(username + ".password"));
        page.clickLoginButton();
```

if I want to use multiple type of user  login in set up method  is it possible and if yes how?

If I want to use employee login in set up method how can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to instantiate multiple `WebDriver` instances and repeat all the configuration code for each one. Hence, invoking login steps for different drivers you will simulate multiple user logins.

You might have a `List<WebDriver> drivers` instead of `WebDriver driver` where you define your drivers.

You also can have something like `login(WebDriver driver, String username)` and do something like:

```java
for(WebDriver driver: drivers){
    login(driver, userNameThatYouHaveTakenFromSomewhere)
}
```